# How to pass ARG as CMD parameter in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I build a container with some arguments. These arguments contain a username, which is also required by the entrypoint.sh. So, I created an ENV which just holds the same value:

```
ARG USERNAME=newman
ENV USERNAME=newman
# ...
CMD ["sh", "/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh", "${USERNAME}"]
```

entrypoint.sh uses it to chown a folder:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
USERNAME=$1
chown -hR "$USERNAME":"$USERNAME" /export
```

Instead, it literally passes `${USERNAME}` into the script.

This is how I call docker build and run:

```bash
docker build \
       --build-arg USERNAME=$(whoami) \
       -t mycontainer:$VERSION} \
       -f ./docker/Dockerfile .

docker run \
       --rm \
       --name mycontainer-$VERSION \
       --env USERNAME=$(whoami) \
       -v $(pwd)/export:/export \
       mycontainer:$VERSION
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're not missing anything; this is working exactly as-designed. Parameter expansion is performed _by a shell_; a JSON list of arguments are passed exactly as they are with no shell involved. It's like running `'sh' '/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh' '${USERNAME}'` in bash.

Comment: If you just delete the `USERNAME=$1` from the script, btw, the variable will be populated from the environment and everything will just work. Think about maybe `: "${USERNAME:=$1}"` as an alternate first line to populate USERNAME from $1 if it's empty or leave it as-is if it isn't.

Comment: And as an aside, using the all-caps name USERNAME is bad form; all-caps names are used by the shell and other POSIX-defined tools, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to have unintended side effects on POSIX-defined tools. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: I might do none of this.  The `docker run -v` bind mount will inherit all of its permissions from the host system, and you can usually `docker run -u $(id -u)` a container as the host user without doing any particular configuration.  So long as that uid has write permission on the host directory, you probably don't need to do any setup in the container or pass in a user name in a process-visible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter expansion is a shell operation. To make it happen, you need to *actually use a shell*.

```
CMD /bin/docker-entrypoint.sh "${USERNAME}"
```

...does this, because it's running:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh \"${USERNAME}\""]
```

which is passing the `${USERNAME}` expansion as part of a string that the shell is parsing as code, not as a literal argument.